# Register with phone number or Email in Asp .net core 2

Tags: asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-2.0, identity, asp.net-core-2.1

Is there any way that user can register whether by email or phone number in asp .net core 2 identity?

I set these true, but i want to check if one of them is true then user can log into site

config.SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail = true;
config.SignIn.RequireConfirmedPhoneNumber = true;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most probably you are using asp.net identity. In asp.net identity uses signinmanager class

```
var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync
```

PasswordSignInAsync method is overloaded as

```
_signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(string UserName, string Password, bool RememberMe, 
bool lockoutOnFailure);
```

or

```
_signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(TUser User, string Password, bool RememberMe, 
    bool lockoutOnFailure);
```

By default it uses first method with `string username`. You can use second method after assigned `User` with email or phone number.

To find user you can use UserManager (You need to do dependency injection for that as well). Try the following:

```
var currentUser= await _userManager.FindByEmailAsync(String email);
var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(currentUser, Input.Password, Input.RememberMe, true);
```